# Catch all call back notification when Dailymotion embed link play in default mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-mediaplayer, dailymotion-api

How to Catch all Call Back Notification for getting .m3u8 or mp4 link  from dailymotion embed link when play in android default media player using web view android?
We  have another solution to get link using html method like this one.

[using Demo #1: How to Embed HLS / M3u8 Streaming: Demo of M3u8 / HLS embedding with HTML5 rollove](http://www.gravlab.com/2013/10/26/example-sample-http-live-streaming-m3u8-embedded-player/)

But i want to get m3u8 link when webview notification through to default mediaplayer of android for playing a video in default android mediaplayer Please help me i am stuck approx 2 weeks Thanks.

I get a code in IOS(Objective C) and in C language level for getting notification of player that code is following

C-Language Level:

```
void PlayerWillExitFullscreen (CFNotificationCenterRef center,
                 void *observer,
                 CFStringRef name,
                 const void *object,
                 CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    //do something...
}

CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetLocalCenter(), 
    NULL, 
    PlayerWillExitFullscreen, 
    CFSTR("UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification"), 
    NULL,  
    CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

Objective-C Level:

```
- (void)playerWillExitFullscreen:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //do something... }

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerWillExitFullscreen:)
                                             name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification" 
                                           object:nil];
```

can any one provide me alternative code in android please help me yet i am stuck